# cURL to self in an XDebug session

Tags: php, xdebug

I'm using XDebug to debug a PHP application in Eclipse. The application calls an HTTP API within itself via cURL:

```
//Current protocol-server-port
$URL = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
if($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != 80)
    $URL .= ':'.$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'];

//Current Web folder
$URI = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$URI = substr($URI, 0, strrpos($URI, '/'));

//Put them together
$URL .= $URI.'/apiendpoint.php';

//On to cURL POST...
```

When I debug the application itself, the breakpoints are hit. However, when the app invokes itself, **breakpoints within apiendpoint.php are not hit**.

I've tried passing query string parameters XDEBUG_SESSION_START and KEY from the app start page to the API URL, to no effect. Any other ideas, please?

Comment: 1) You can try with `xdebug.remote_autostart = 1` so it will attempt to debug **every single request** regardless of "debug me" cookie/param. 2) You may also try placing `xdebug_break();` in your code to see if it will make any difference (programmatic breakpoint) 3) What xdebug log says about such 2nd debug session (*"when the app invokes itself"*) -- does it even tries to start? Maybe it tries to connect to wrong IP:port? 4) Is your IDE (debug client) supports multiple simultaneous debug sessions? If you already debugging app and it calls itself -- that would be separate/2nd session.

Comment: xdebug_break() didn't work, I'll try the rest.