# Xdebug 2.9.8 not breaking at breakpoints in NetBeans 8.1 in some situations

Tags: debugging, netbeans, xdebug, breakpoints

I have a PHP application, for which I am trying to create an API. I use NetBeans IDE 8.1 for my PHP project. I use php 7.4 with Xdebug 2.9.8.

Breakpoints work fine, when I debug the application using a browser, such as pointing the browser to the file where breakpoints are set. For example api/index.php.

The problem is that when I try using the API, for example from an Android emulator running locally that reaches the PHP app using HttpsURLConnection, the file is reached but the debugger does NOT break at breakpoints.

I also tried using curl in my PHP app to call itself, same problem, file is reached and executed but breakpoints are not working. Tried using curl calls with GET and POST, also with `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug");`

My environment:

```
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
Apache 2 with PHP 7.4
```

Xdebug settings:

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20190902/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable = true
; xdebug.mode = debug
; xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
; xdebug.remote_log_level = 10
; xdebug.remote_log = /tmp/xdebug.log
```

I tried all suggestings from [cURL to self in an XDebug session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46514321/curl-to-self-in-an-xdebug-session) with the following results:

`xdebug.remote_autostart = 1`
This results in curl calls hanging forever.

`xdebug_break();` - does not break.
Also tried using this:

```
$debugger_active = xdebug_is_debugger_active();
if ($debugger_active)
  error_log("Debugger is active");
else
  error_log("Debugger is NOT active...");
```

Debugger is NOT active when I use the API, active during normal debugging when breakpoints are reached.

I was not able to see Xdebug logs (with uncommented `xdebug.remote_log`).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Xdebug 2 is no longer supported, please upgrade. Xdebug 3 has much better logging, and also a new `xdebug_info()` function which shows a lot more detail of what it is (or isn't) trying to do.

Secondly, if there is no output in the file pointed to by `xdebug.remote_log`, than 1. there is an issue with file permissions, or 2. Xdebug never attempted to make a connection to your IDE.

Comment: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug");` — the cookie is called `XDEBUG_SESSION` and not `XDEBUG_SESSION_START`, which can only be used as GET or POST parameter.

Comment: `xdebug.remote_autostart = 1 This results in curl calls hanging forever.` — or perhaps multiple connections are active at the same time? Does Netbeans support that? Xdebug's log should tell you again. If you don't have one, Xdebug didn't try to make a connection.

Comment: Thanks Derick. I tried using XDEBUG_SESSION cookie without luck so far. For now, instead of PHP, I use a Java Servlet app in the same IDE to debug API calls from Android emulator, which breaks at my breakpoints normally, as expected. I may try updating Xdebug later to see if it helps.